# JS - FullCalendar showing cropped events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar in a Bootstrap-based website in which I have two columns, the left one uses 9 bootstrap columns and the aside uses 3, and the calendar is in the aside.
[image: cropped events calendar]

The problem is events appear cropped due to the lack of space.

What I want to do is that, instead of the event being cropped, the day height will grow to accomodate the content.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        locale: 'es',
        events: [
          {
            title: 'Prueba 1',
            start: '2017-05-04'
          },
          {
            title: 'Prueba 2',
            start: '2017-05-23'
          },
          {
            title: 'Prueba tiempo',
            start: '2017-05-24T12:30:00',
            allDay: false
          }
        ],
         eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
           alert(calEvent.title + " : " + moment(calEvent.start).format("DD/MM hh:mm"));
        }
      });
  });
```

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried setting a minimum height for the calendar element using CSS?

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework of width setting on the element where the calendar is generated? Check there first.